# Using loops to make multiple plots with selected information information in dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, plot

I have a dataframe that looks like this and I would like to use a for-loop to make plots that have the Survival on the y-axis and Time on the x-axis, for each line, sex and dose combination. So for example, I want one plot for the Survival Vs. time for Females of line 138 at dose 1, then another for males of line 138 at dose 1 and so on. How can I do that?

| Time | Survival | Line | Sex | Dose |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 28 | 0.95 | 138 | F | 1 |
| 35 | 0.65 | 138 | F | 1 |
| 41 | 0.6 | 138 | F | 1 |
| 42 | 0.15 | 138 | F | 1 |
| 48 | 0.05 | 138 | F | 1 |
| 55 | 0 | 138 | F | 1 |
| 5 | 0.95 | 138 | F | 1 |
| 11 | 0.855 | 138 | F | 1 |
| 28 | 0.95 | 138 | M | 1 |
| 35 | 0.65 | 138 | M | 1 |
| 41 | 0.6 | 138 | M | 1 |
| 42 | 0.15 | 138 | M | 1 |
| 48 | 0.05 | 138 | M | 1 |
| 55 | 0 | 138 | M | 1 |
| 5 | 0.95 | 138 | M | 1 |
| 11 | 0.855 | 138 | M | 1 |
| 28 | 0.95 | 120 | F | 2 |
| 35 | 0.65 | 120 | F | 2 |
| 41 | 0.6 | 120 | F | 2 |
| 42 | 0.15 | 120 | F | 2 |
| 48 | 0.05 | 120 | F | 2 |
| 55 | 0 | 120 | F | 2 |
| 5 | 0.95 | 120 | F | 2 |
| 11 | 0.855 | 120 | F | 2 |
| 28 | 0.95 | 120 | M | 2 |
| 35 | 0.65 | 120 | M | 2 |
| 41 | 0.6 | 120 | M | 2 |
| 42 | 0.15 | 120 | M | 2 |
| 48 | 0.05 | 120 | M | 2 |
| 55 | 0 | 120 | M | 2 |
| 5 | 0.95 | 120 | M | 2 |
| 11 | 0.855 | 120 | M | 2 |

Comment: Several current graphic packages (ggplot2, plotly, highcharter, lattice ...) have dedicated functionality for *facetting* plots by categories. See, e. g. [`facet_wrap`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/index.html#facetting)

Answer (score 0):

This should work, assuming your data frame is named `df` and `class(df) == "data.frame"`:

```
library(ggplot2)

combinations <- unique(df[, c("Line", "Sex", "Dose")])

for (i in 1:nrow(combinations)) {
  line <- combinations$Line[i]
  sex <- combinations$Sex[i]
  dose <- combinations$Dose[i]

  subdata <- df[df$Line == line & df$Sex == sex & df$Dose == dose, ]
  
  plot <- ggplot(subdata, aes(x = Time, y = Survival)) + geom_line() + labs(title = paste("Line", line, ", Sex", sex, ", Dose", dose),
         x = "Time", y = "Survival")
  print(plot)
}
```

The data you gave makes identical plots though.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Also, if I wanted to plot survival on the y-axis and dose on the x-axis for just one time point (lets say time=11) for each sex and line combination, how would the code change?

Comment: You could filter your data frame like this `df_filtered <- df[df$Time == 11, ]`, the combination changes a little bit : `combinations <- unique(df_filtered[, c("Line", "Sex")])`. Then in the next part of the code just change the axis to get what you want

Answer (score 0):

This is straightforward using `ggplot`, without any loops.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(Time, Survival)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(paste('Sex:', Sex) ~ paste('Line', Line) + paste('Dose', Dose)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using `plot` in `by`.

```
> par(mfrow=with(dat, table(Sex, Dose)) |> dim())
> transform(dat, fac=Reduce(paste0, data.frame(Sex, Dose))) |>
+   by(~fac, \(x) plot(Survival ~ Time, x, type='s', main=el(fac)))
```

[image]

If we have too much combinations, we'd need a different `par` approach.

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(Time = c(28L, 35L, 41L, 42L, 48L, 55L, 5L, 11L, 
28L, 35L, 41L, 42L, 48L, 55L, 5L, 11L, 28L, 35L, 41L, 42L, 48L, 
55L, 5L, 11L, 28L, 35L, 41L, 42L, 48L, 55L), Survival = c(0.95, 
0.65, 0.6, 0.15, 0.05, 0, 0.95, 0.855, 0.95, 0.65, 0.6, 0.15, 
0.05, 0, 0.95, 0.855, 0.95, 0.65, 0.6, 0.15, 0.05, 0, 0.95, 0.855, 
0.95, 0.65, 0.6, 0.15, 0.05, 0), Line = c(138L, 138L, 138L, 138L, 
138L, 138L, 138L, 138L, 138L, 138L, 138L, 138L, 138L, 138L, 138L, 
138L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 
120L, 120L, 120L, 120L), Sex = c("F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M"), Dose = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm also having trouble with the following: If I wanted to go through my dataframe and save "survival" at each "dose" at a specified time (let's say time =11) for each line and sex combination, into separate dataframes, how could I do that using a for-loop?

Comment: @K.W You probably want `subset(dat, Time == 11)`. You should ask this as a new question, though.